# User-specific virtual machines in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to start many [VMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) created by different users on the same Linux host?

I want to start four virtual machines with my own user name and start four with another user name at the same time on the same host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have powerful enough host or low requirements for the virtual machines, then it certainly is possible - the best way to find out is to try it.

That said, depending on your needs, OS-level virtualisation like [LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) might serve you better.

Comment: My problem is that I have some scripts which are trying to connect to does machines and reboot them etc, but when there are more than one users; running vms commands like ssh will result in conflicts. Guest machines are using same ip subnets. Perhaps I should change the ips for each user, or?

Comment: Of course you have to give each VM a different IP address - it's no different from having a "physical" network. IP address conflicts are just wrong.